# How to find the deviation using Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, swing

I would like to find out the deviation between two drawing lines using the following code but for some reason it just feels wrong.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawLine extends JPanel {  

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  LinePoint[] lineA = new LinePoint[5];
  LinePoint[] lineB = new LinePoint[5];

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

     for(int i = 0; i < lineA.length; i++) {
         lineA[i] =  new LinePoint();
         lineB[i] =  new LinePoint();

     }

     int initialLocationPoint = 10;
     for(int i = 0; i<lineA.length; i++) {
         lineA[i].x = initialLocationPoint;
         lineA[i].y = 100;
         lineB[i].x = initialLocationPoint;
         lineB[i].y = 100;
         g.drawOval((int)lineA[i].x, (int)lineA[i].y, 1, 1);
         g.drawOval((int)lineB[i].x, (int)lineB[i].y, 1, 1);
         initialLocationPoint +=1; 
     }

     System.out.println("DEVIATION: " + this.calculateDifference());

  }

  public double calculateDifference() {
      double deviation = 0.0;
      double deviationPerCordinate = 0.0;
      for (int i = 0; i < lineA.length; i++) {
          deviationPerCordinate = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(2, (lineB[i].x - lineA[i].x))  + Math.pow(2,(lineB[i].y - lineA[i].y)));
          System.out.println("deviationPerCordinate " + i + ": " + deviationPerCordinate);
          deviation = deviation + deviationPerCordinate;
      }
      return deviation;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Line");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);

    DrawLine panel = new DrawLine();

    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

**RESULT:**

deviationPerCordinate 0: 1.4142135623730951

deviationPerCordinate 1: 1.4142135623730951

deviationPerCordinate 2: 1.4142135623730951

deviationPerCordinate 3: 1.4142135623730951

deviationPerCordinate 4: 1.4142135623730951

DEVIATION: 7.0710678118654755

**EXPTECTED RESULT:**

Shouldn't this return 0? as there is no difference at all since both drawings are at the same positions/cords.

Anyone knows what Am I doing wrong here? Is it the formula?

Comment: Can you say the definition of what are you calculating and why do you need it?

Comment: I am trying to see the difference/distance from two lines, delta, deviation idk how to call it. I need it for fun!

Comment: "I don't know how to call it" = I don't know what do i want to do

Comment: fixed it: deviationPerCordinate = Math.sqrt((lineB[i].y - lineA[i].y) * (lineB[i].y - lineA[i].y) + (lineB[i].x - lineA[i].x) * (lineB[i].x - lineA[i].x));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming that you are using the Euclidean distance to calculate the deviation, you formula is wrong. The correct way to square a value in Java using Math library is `Math.pow(x, 2)`. That being said, this `Math.pow(2, (lineB[i].x - lineA[i].x))` should be `Math.pow((lineB[i].x - lineA[i].x), 2)` and same for the `y` coordinate.